# struts 2 validation don't work, why?

Tags: validation, struts2

I implemented some actions in a Struts2+J2EE environment. I'd like to validate inputs with the struts validation framework: my package extends struts-default, my action extends Action Support and I put the xml file (MyActionClassName-validations.xml) in the same folder of my action. It doesn't work!
Could I do something to check if validation framework works at all?
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, the file should be named MyActionClassName-validation.xml (without the trailing s in "validation"). Also check that this xml file is deployed correctly with your application.